# For float num with 0-2 decimals, if x+y=z in decimal and MIN_VALUE<=x,y,z<=MAX_VALUE, is Number.parseFloat((x+y).toFixed(2))==z always true?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, parsefloat, tofixed

For example, I know 0.1+0.2 == 0.3 is false because float number is not accurate sometimes. After adding toFixed(2) following Number.parseFloat, it becomes true:

```js
console.log(0.1+0.2 == 0.3);
console.log(Number.parseFloat((0.1+0.2).toFixed(2))==0.3);
```

However, I want to know the general case of it: for float numbers x,y,z with 0-2 decimals (x,y may have different number of decimals, eg: 1.35+7.9),if x+y exactly equals to z in decimal form, and Number.MIN_VALUE <= x,y,z <= Number.MAX_VALUE, is

```
Number.parseFloat((x+y).toFixed(2))==z
```

always true? If so, besides x+y, are x-y,x*y,x/y (without x/0) also implies in this case? If not, when would it be false?

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing `Number.parseFloat((0.1+0.2).toFixed(2))==0.3`

`(0.1+0.2).toFixed(2)` creates a string `"0.30"`. parseFloat() scans the string and creates the number`~0.299999999999999989` (printed by `(0.30).toPrecision(18)`). The number at the right is scanned by the parser and converted to the same number. So the result is `true`.

The rule is: Use formatting functions like toFixed() or toPrecision() only to generate output, but never for mathematical calculations.

If you need exact 1/100 (cents instead of dollar), then calculate in cents and use `(num/100).toFixed(2)` for the output. btw, banking software calculate very often in 0.00001 steps. So they print by `(num/100000).toFixed(2)`.

### Your question

Back to your question: Is `Number.parseFloat((x+y).toFixed(2))==z` always true (if `z=x+y`)?

Yes it is with exception of very large or very small numbers (precision issues).

Answer (score 0):

No.  For "float num with 0-2 decimals", which for this question is implied to be any rational number evenly divisable by 0.01 (since none of the given example numbers--0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.35, and 7.9--are exactly representable by a float), if x+y=z in decimal and MIN_VALUE<=x,y,z<=MAX_VALUE, Number.parseFloat((x+y).toFixed(2))==z is **NOT always true**.  Here is the proof by contradiction:

```
                  1
 1234567890000000.37
+               1.03
--------------------
 1234567890000001.40

>
console.log(Number.parseFloat((1234567890000000.37+1.03).toFixed(2))==1234567890000001.40);
false
undefined
>
```